# how i can convert std::string to NvU16[]?

Tags: c++, string, stl, nvapi

i cant correct convert from std::string to NvU16[]
where:

```
typedef NvU16 NvAPI_UnicodeString[NVAPI_UNICODE_STRING_MAX];
```

also:

```
typedef const NvU16 *NvAPI_LPCWSTR;
```

Comment: Could you perhaps share with us what `NvU16` is?

Comment: typedef unsigned short   NvU16;

Comment: I need convert std::string to NvAPI_UnicodeString. I do it use written by me function with for loop. How i can do it without using my function?

Comment: `NvAPI_UnicodeString` is the name of your array. When you "convert" a string, what do you want the contents of that array to become? What have you tried?